# System of equations not being solved after an hour of waiting

Tags: python, sympy, equation

I was trying to solve a non-linear system that consists of two equations with 2 unknowns, I tried using Sympy module to complete the task.
After trying to run the code below (on Atom and Google Collab notebook), nothing is happening and the process is never terminated (waited for over that 15min).
What could be the problem? is my system to complicated?
**I tried to use fsolve from scipy and i was able to get one of the roots in no time**

*This is the code below*

```
import sympy as sym

sym.init_printing()
x,y = sym.symbols('x,y')
dmin = 70 #minimum of the actuator
dmax = 140 #maximum of the actuator

l3 = 10
l4 = 10

Amin = 0.523599 #min angle in radians
Amax = 2.0944 #max angle in radians

cos1 = sym.cos(Amin - sym.atan(l4/x) - sym.atan(l3/y))
cos2 = sym.cos(Amax - sym.atan(l4/x) - sym.atan(l3/y))

a2 = x**2 + l4**2
b2 = y**2 + l3**2

f=sym.Eq(a2 + b2 - 2*sym.sqrt(a2)*sym.sqrt(b2)*cos1, dmin**2)
g=sym.Eq(a2 + b2 - 2*sym.sqrt(a2)*sym.sqrt(b2)*cos2, dmax**2)

print(sym.solve([f,g],(x,y)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equations are like:

```
In [160]: f
Out[160]: 
               __________    __________                                                 
 2    2       ╱  2          ╱  2           ⎛    ⎛10⎞       ⎛10⎞           ⎞             
x  + y  - 2⋅╲╱  x  + 100 ⋅╲╱  y  + 100 ⋅cos⎜atan⎜──⎟ + atan⎜──⎟ - 0.523599⎟ + 200 = 4900
                                           ⎝    ⎝x ⎠       ⎝y ⎠           ⎠             

In [161]: g
Out[161]: 
               __________    __________                                                
 2    2       ╱  2          ╱  2           ⎛    ⎛10⎞       ⎛10⎞         ⎞              
x  + y  - 2⋅╲╱  x  + 100 ⋅╲╱  y  + 100 ⋅cos⎜atan⎜──⎟ + atan⎜──⎟ - 2.0944⎟ + 200 = 19600
                                           ⎝    ⎝x ⎠       ⎝y ⎠         ⎠
```

Usually a mix of algebraic and transcendental functions like this would not have any anlytic solution but in this case the `cos` can cancel with the `atan` to make purely algebraic equations:

```
In [162]: expand_trig(f)
Out[162]: 
               __________    __________                                                                                                                                                     
 2    2       ╱  2          ╱  2        ⎛      0.866025291583566                 5.00000194337561                  5.00000194337561                   86.6025291583566        ⎞             
x  + y  - 2⋅╲╱  x  + 100 ⋅╲╱  y  + 100 ⋅⎜───────────────────────────── + ─────────────────────────────── + ─────────────────────────────── - ─────────────────────────────────⎟ + 200 = 4900
                                        ⎜     _________      _________          _________      _________          _________      _________            _________      _________⎟             
                                        ⎜    ╱     100      ╱     100          ╱     100      ╱     100          ╱     100      ╱     100            ╱     100      ╱     100 ⎟             
                                        ⎜   ╱  1 + ─── ⋅   ╱  1 + ───    y⋅   ╱  1 + ─── ⋅   ╱  1 + ───    x⋅   ╱  1 + ─── ⋅   ╱  1 + ───    x⋅y⋅   ╱  1 + ─── ⋅   ╱  1 + ─── ⎟             
                                        ⎜  ╱         2    ╱         2        ╱         2    ╱         2        ╱         2    ╱         2          ╱         2    ╱         2 ⎟             
                                        ⎝╲╱         x   ╲╱         y       ╲╱         x   ╲╱         y       ╲╱         x   ╲╱         y         ╲╱         x   ╲╱         y  ⎠             

In [163]: expand_trig(g)
Out[163]: 
               __________    __________                                                                                                                                                        
 2    2       ╱  2          ╱  2        ⎛        0.500004241445914                 8.6602295497065                   8.6602295497065                    50.0004241445914        ⎞              
x  + y  - 2⋅╲╱  x  + 100 ⋅╲╱  y  + 100 ⋅⎜- ───────────────────────────── + ─────────────────────────────── + ─────────────────────────────── + ─────────────────────────────────⎟ + 200 = 19600
                                        ⎜       _________      _________          _________      _________          _________      _________            _________      _________⎟              
                                        ⎜      ╱     100      ╱     100          ╱     100      ╱     100          ╱     100      ╱     100            ╱     100      ╱     100 ⎟              
                                        ⎜     ╱  1 + ─── ⋅   ╱  1 + ───    y⋅   ╱  1 + ─── ⋅   ╱  1 + ───    x⋅   ╱  1 + ─── ⋅   ╱  1 + ───    x⋅y⋅   ╱  1 + ─── ⋅   ╱  1 + ─── ⎟              
                                        ⎜    ╱         2    ╱         2        ╱         2    ╱         2        ╱         2    ╱         2          ╱         2    ╱         2 ⎟              
                                        ⎝  ╲╱         x   ╲╱         y       ╲╱         x   ╲╱         y       ╲╱         x   ╲╱         y         ╲╱         x   ╲╱         y  ⎠
```

Using this we can massage the system into a pair of polynomials and then solve it with Groebner bases:

```
In [181]: from sympy.solvers.solvers import unrad

In [174]: eq1 = trigsimp(unrad(expand_trig(nsimplify(f)).rewrite(Add))[0]/(x*y)).factor().args[-1]

In [175]: eq2 = trigsimp(unrad(expand_trig(nsimplify(g)).rewrite(Add))[0]/(x*y)).factor().args[-1]

In [176]: gb = groebner([nsimplify(eq1.n()), nsimplify(eq2.n())], [x, y])

In [177]: for p in gb: print(p.n(2))
x - 2.9e-27*y**15 - 4.4e-25*y**14 + 2.8e-22*y**13 + 4.2e-20*y**12 - 1.2e-17*y**11 - 1.6e-15*y**10 + 2.7e-13*y**9 + 3.2e-11*y**8 - 3.6e-9*y**7 - 3.6e-7*y**6 + 2.7e-5*y**5 + 0.0021*y**4 - 0.099*y**3 - 6.2*y**2 + 1.3e+2*y + 6.5e+3
y**16 + 1.4e+2*y**15 - 1.0e+5*y**14 - 1.3e+7*y**13 + 4.4e+9*y**12 + 4.7e+11*y**11 - 1.1e+14*y**10 - 9.0e+15*y**9 + 1.5e+18*y**8 + 9.3e+19*y**7 - 1.3e+22*y**6 - 5.1e+23*y**5 + 6.3e+25*y**4 + 1.3e+27*y**3 - 1.5e+29*y**2 - 1.2e+30*y + 1.3e+32

In [178]: ry = [r.n() for r in real_roots(gb[-1])]

In [179]: ry
Out[179]: 
[-112.210054906433, -94.6849042632114, -53.6834203472101, -49.4635109350851, 48.579017974275, 50.194835
2176397, 82.5120279645666, 103.812504924146, 118.173390238157, 142.710285016351]

In [180]: for yval in ry:
     ...:     print('y =', yval, ', x =', solve(gb[0].subs(y, yval), x)[0])
     ...: 
y = -112.210054906433 , x = 48.5790179742034
y = -94.6849042632114 , x = -53.6834203471953
y = -53.6834203472101 , x = -94.6849042632093
y = -49.4635109350851 , x = 103.812504924146
y = 48.5790179742750 , x = -112.210054906433
y = 50.1948352176397 , x = 118.173390238151
y = 82.5120279645666 , x = 142.710285016423
y = 103.812504924146 , x = -49.4635109348164
y = 118.173390238157 , x = 50.1948352170293
y = 142.710285016351 , x = 82.5120279639959
```

Rewriting as polynomial introduces spurious solutions so only some of those are actually solutions of `f` and `g`.

A simpler and faster way to compute these solutions if you have an initial guess for a particular solution that you want is just to use `nsolve` to solve the system numerically:

```
In [194]: nsolve([f, g], [x, y], [118, 50])
Out[194]: 
⎡118.173390238157⎤
⎢                ⎥
⎣50.1948352176396⎦
```

Comment: how did you solve for the atan? what if the values of l3, l4. dmin, dmax, Amin and Amax changes, how can I make this transformation dynamic.

Comment: btw, the answer i was looking for is exactly the one you found using nsolve, how is that possible? I'm very much confused

Comment: The atan and cos can cancel (`expand_trig`). For different values of the parameters both methods described above should still work

Answer (score 0):

This is another good candidate for the [continuation method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72631933/1089161). The discussion is at the link but I would apply it as follows using `c` to control the more non-linear term of your equations:

```
import sympy as sym
x,y = sym.symbols('x,y')
dmin = 70 #minimum of the actuator
dmax = 140 #maximum of the actuator

l3 = 10
l4 = 10

Amin = 0.523599 #min angle in radians
Amax = 2.0944 #max angle in radians
for c in range(10):
    c=c/S(10)
    cos1 = sym.cos(Amin - sym.atan(l4/x)*c - sym.atan(l3/y)*c)
    cos2 = sym.cos(Amax - sym.atan(l4/x)*c - sym.atan(l3/y)*c)
    a2 = x**2 + l4**2
    b2 = y**2 + l3**2
    f=sym.Eq(a2 + b2 - 2*sym.sqrt(a2)*sym.sqrt(b2)*cos1, dmin**2)
    g=sym.Eq(a2 + b2 - 2*sym.sqrt(a2)*sym.sqrt(b2)*cos2, dmax**2)
    if not c:
        gs = solve((f,g),(x,y),dict=False)
    else:
        sol = []
        for gi in gs:
            sol.append(nsolve((f,g),(x,y),gi))
```

`gs` starts out as

```
[(-107.967591836877, -48.6044884662980), 
(-107.967591836877, 48.6044884662980),
(-48.6044884662980, -107.967591836877),
(-48.6044884662980, 107.967591836877),
(48.6044884662980, -107.967591836877),
(48.6044884662980, 107.967591836877),
(107.967591836877, -48.6044884662980),
(107.967591836877, 48.6044884662980)]
```

and is gradually modified as `c` goes to 1 to become the final solution

```
>>> for i in ordered(sol):tuple(i)
...
(-111.790176548536, 48.5400429865187)
(-96.2635727943765, -52.7612279529407)
(-52.7612279529407, -96.2635727943765)
(-49.3470005072566, 104.216202951134)
(48.5400429865187, -111.790176548536)
(49.8069789979713, 117.241028072945)
(104.216202951134, -49.3470005072566)
(117.241028072945, 49.8069789979713)
```